# How can I trace the attributes of an AS3 shared object's data property? (Not the values but the attributes themselves)

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm writing a game in actionscript 3, I have a shared object that saves what inventory items you have collected. The data attributes of this shared object are for example:

```
inventorySO.data.appleInventory = false;
inventorySO.data.branchInventory = false;
inventorySO.data.tamagotchiInventory = false;
```

I've already worked out how to loop through the data attributes, is there any way that I can trace each data attribute so that my output is:

appleInventory

branchInventory

tamagotchiInventory

and not:

false

false

false

I couldn't see anything in the reference docs or online, so thanks very much to anyone who's able to help!

Romano

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [`for..in`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/statements.html#for..in) loop:

```
for(var prop:String in inventorySO.data)
{
    trace(prop);
}
```

Note that in this loop, you can access the value of each property iterated using:

```
inventorySO.data[prop];
```